# How to switch the login landing page for different types of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two different types of users (Admin, Teacher). Admin has entire permission to view all, so when he tries to login a page and it should land to `'home#index'` page. When Teacher tries to login it should land to `'localhost:3000/post/new'` instead of `'home#index'`

Routes file contain:

```
resources :session, :only => [:update]
   match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
   match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
   root to: 'home#index'
```

So, how do i switch the login page for users of type Teacher `'home#index'` to land on a different page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a compelling reason you can't just add a conditional to your index action that redirects if the incoming user is a Teacher?

```
if user.teacher?
  redirect_to new_post_path
end
```

Something like that?  Seems like it'd be easier than screwing around with routes.